# Evaluating $\int \frac{x\sin x-\cos x}{x\left(2\cos x+x-x\sin x\right)} {\rm d} x$ using elementary methods

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

I know how to evaluate elementary integrals. However, I encountered the following integral and was unable to how to solve it.

$$\int \frac{x\sin x-\cos x}{x\left(2\cos x+x-x\sin x\right)} {\rm d} x$$

The derivative of denominator is not present in the numerator too. Can't think of any substitution either. Breaking about the numerator also fails. WolframAlpha also fails.

Can someone help me evaluate the integral above, preferably using elementary methods?

Comment: If WolframAlpha fails, I wouldn't hold out much hope. I can also confirm that Mathematica doesn't give an antiderivative. (It also just doesn't look very likely.)

Answer (score 0):

Check if denominator has sinx^2, cause taking a substitution xcosx = t, the denominator will be 2t +t^2, and it will be easy to solve, and the answer will be log(1+2/xcosx)^(1/2).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I think it is clear. Replace $-x\sin x$ by $-x\sin^2x$ in the denominator.